# Using ofstream whenever ostream is required

Tags: c++, ofstream, ostream

I am using a library and it has a function:

`static void printSingleExpr(std::ostream &os, const ref<Expr> &e);`

However, I want to output to a file using `ofstream` rather than the `std::ostream` and when I pass an `ofstream` instance (as kind of expected) I am getting an error. Is there any way to achieve this *without* modifying the function itself (or overloading the function) ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must be passing it something wrong. `std::ofstream` inherits from, and can thus be used in place of, `std::ostream`. In other words, the following should work:

```
std::ofstream f("x.bin");
printSingleExpr(f, x);
```

Make sure your `std::ofstream` reference isn't constant or volatile for some reason.

Comment: Thanks, I think I am doing some other silly mistake with other arguments which is the real cause of the problem